# Exist a name or a category to describe set of negative integers Z- under subtraction?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, category-theory

Question is this: what algebraic structure forms the set of negative integers Z- under subtraction?

There is no such algebraic structure. 
**But exists a name, a label or a category to describe this mathematical entity situation if we can't circumscribe into an algebraic structure?**

> The set of negative integers is not closed under subtraction. For example, (−3)−(−5) is not a negative integer.
>   Furthermore, subtraction is not associative. For example, ((−5)−(−2))−(−1)=−2 but (−5)−((−2)−(−1))=−4.
>
> Any group-like algebraic structure (set with a binary operation) that does not require closure (groupoid, semigroupoid, small category) requires associativity. Any group-like structure that does not require associativity (magma, quasigroup, loop) requires closure.

If you get rid of both closure and associativity, there’s really nothing left in terms of an algebraic structure.
You could make it a partially closed operation—groupoids have that property, for instance. The more damning problem, I think, is that subtraction is not associative

Comment: Without significant exception, as far as I know, nobody uses algebraic structures with operations which aren't "closed" on the underlying set.  Actually, most texts don't even use the terminology "closed" when defining an operation, because the definition of a binary operation includes it implicitly. They *do* use "closed" to refer describe substructures which inherit the operation from a structure containing them, though.

Comment: You have a set and a partial binary operation. It's a "partial magma". But you don't get much out of that. Partial algebras are already difficult to deal with, and magmas don't have a lot of structure to work with. Put the two together, and you basically have got almost nothing to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right: there probably is no term. Almost nobody (or nobody at all?) deals with operations that "aren't closed."

I would recommend looking at it this way: from your original set $X$ and "operation" "$\circ$", let $Y=X\cup \{x\circ y\mid x,y\in X\}$.  Then you could call $(Y,\circ)$ a "magma with a partial operation" or something like that.

For your specific example, you would actually have a full-fledged magma with $(\mathbb Z, -)$.

I was going to suggest "magmoid" since I've read that "groupoids" sometimes refer to partially defined operations, but I found people using magmoid for something else already. Well, being explicit with "magma with a partial operation" is probably better anyhow.

Comment: What does it mean "ful-fledged" ? Also division of real numbers is a partial binary operation. How can one distinguish a partial binary operation (in my case substraction) from another partial binary operation (division)?

Comment: @Jag typo, but anyhow https://www.dictionary.com/browse/full-fledged

Comment: I don’t know if I understand what you’re asking in the comment above at the end.  Operations depend on a function defined on a set... of the set doesn’t distinguish two operations, then the behavior of the function will.

Comment: mm..If I choose $Z$ as a set and I define a 'substraction' $(\mathbb -)$ on this set I talk about of 'partial binary operation' that is a partial function but the set of complex numbers is closed under subtraction so in this situation we talk about of binary operation. I rhink that don't depend by a function but by *set* function

Comment: @Jag As far as I can tell, what you said matches what I said.